# countdown time for multiple row in db

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am working on this kind for countdown time for multiple row in db. I have different time stored in my database.. And I want script bellow to show countdown time for each row..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdownTimer.js"></script>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php $x = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM payment");
while($xx = mysqli_fetch_array($x))
{ ?>
```

HTML and Javascript

```
<span id="future_date"></span>
<script>
 $(function(){
 $('#future_date').countdowntimer({
 dateAndTime : "<?php echo $xx['stop_time']; ?>",
 size : "lg",
 regexpMatchFormat: "([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2})",
 regexpReplaceWith: "$1:$2:$3:$4"
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Close php

```
<?php } ?>
```

for DB

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `userid`, `stop_time`) VALUES
(1, '3', '2017-04-20'),
(2, '2', '2017-04-12');
(3, '9', '2017-05-10');
(4, '3', '2017-03-22');
(5, '7', '2017-04-01');
(6, '9', '2017-04-10');
```

I use the code but only show for one row not all the row in db.

Kindly show me what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding id selector every time in a loop.

Make unique id for each timer:

Try this and let me know if this works for you.

```
<?php $x = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM payment");
$i=0;
while($xx = mysqli_fetch_array($x))
{ ?>

<span id="future_date_<?php echo $i ;?>"></span>
<script>
 $(function(){
     $('#future_date_<?php echo $i ;?>').countdowntimer({
         dateAndTime : "<?php echo $xx['stop_time']; ?>",
         size : "lg",
         regexpMatchFormat: "([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2})",
         regexpReplaceWith: "$1:$2:$3:$4"
     });
 });
 </script>

 <?php $i++;} ?>
```